# Style to make a slider instead than checkbox not working even if I override the inline eelement.style

Tags: html, css

my goal is to put [this](http://codepen.io/bbodine1/pen/novBm) slide (the third slide) in [this site](http://glamourina.pl/6-porad-jak-byc-profesjonalna-blogerka-na-evencie-modowym-bloggers-tv-9-odcinek/#dodajkomentarzlink) in the comment boxes.
I took the original CSS code, and I replaced the classes. [This](http://glamourina.pl/wp-content/themes/celebritypress5/slidebuttons.css) is the final CSS you can see now live..

All seems to be fine, apart from the fact that label text doesn't appear next to the checkbox.

Here it is:

```
<label class="subscribe-label" id="subscribe-label" for="subscribe_comments" style="display: inline;">Powiadom mnie o kolejnych komentarzach przez email.</label>
```

The above bold text should show next to the checkbox.

The problem is that I cannot edit the html... I have only access to the CSS. In the CSS I already put the `!important` to override the styles applied inline.
Does anybody know whether it is feasible to achieve it?

P.s. [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pikk/HBuqW/) for tests.

Answer (score 0):

Your label content needs to go here:

## Content in CSS

```
.ondisplay section::before {
  content:'Powiadom mnie o kolejnych komentarzach przez email.'; 
}
```

## HTML

```
<div class="ondisplay">
<section>
  <!-- Slide THREE -->
  <div class="slideThree">  
      <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="slideThree" name="check" checked />
      <label for="slideThree"></label>
  </div>
</section>

</div>
```

## CSS

```
body {
    background: #555;
}

h1, h2 {
    color: #eee;
    font: 30px Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px black;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 0 50px 0;
}

/* SLIDE THREE */
.slideThree {
    width: 80px;
    height: 26px;
    background: #333;
    margin: 20px auto;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.slideThree:after {
    content: 'OFF';
    font: 12px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.15);
}

.slideThree:before {
    content: 'ON';
    font: 12px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #00bf00;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.slideThree label {
    display: block;
    width: 34px;
    height: 20px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;

    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    z-index: 1;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background: #fcfff4;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead',GradientType=0 );
}

.slideThree input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    left: 43px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.ondisplay{
  text-align:center;
  border-bottom:1px solid gray;
  padding:20px 0;
}

.ondisplay section{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background: #555;
  display:inline-block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px
     rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px
     rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}

.ondisplay section::before {
  content:'Powiadom mnie o kolejnych komentarzach przez email.'; 
  color: #bbb;
    font: 15px Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px black;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
}}
```

## Example

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/CXn3v/

Comment: Hi, this can be done editing the html. But this is done via a plugin and I cannot edit the html.

Comment: @Pikk this IS done through the CSS file as you have previously requested. The HTML is intact an unchanged from the js script.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Hi, the HTML is not intact. Because the original HTML is `<label for="slideThree">Powiadom mnie o kolejnych komentarzach przez email.</label>`, but you edited it and you gave `<label for="slideThree"></label>`. This is hardcoded in the Jetpack plugin and cannot be changed.

Comment: @Pikk HTML is intact, referenced from the CodePen link you posted above.

Comment: Codepen is where I took the code from. I edited it (only the CSS part) and applied to the blog - you can see it in the jsfiddle I published. The one in the fiddle should be the one that needs to work, because it is the live example available in the site as well.